# Filter JSON value encapsulated inside HTML DOM using Regex

Tags: php, jquery, json, regex

I am writing a crawler to scrap price information from online stores, I am using Goutte PHP and it does not support javascript interactions, it just grab static HTML DOM, so the issue is in my response of my crawler price, stock information are hidden in HTML DOM inside script tag which is further encapsulated with JSON, here is the data I get

```
<script>
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setSpaceId('33503761');
HZ.data.Variations.put('33503761', {"availVar": [{"id": "c", "label": "Color", "options": [{"name": "Chrome", "avail": 1, "stock": 1, "price": "$174.51", "quantity": "52", "imageId": "3eb1230d05775d3c"}, {"name": "SuperSteel", "avail": 1, "stock": 0, "price": "$341.40", "quantity": "0", "imageId": "d0a126f505775d3e"}]}], "curVar": {"c": "SuperSteel"}, "exactMatch": true});
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setSelector(HZ.productVariation.ListSelector);
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setRenderer(HZ.productVariation.ViewSpaceRenderer);
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setHistoryManager(new HZ.productVariation.BrowserHistoryManager("replace"));
$('.variationSelectors').append(HZ.productVariation.Manager.drawSelectors('33503761'));

HZ.productVariation.Manager.initUI();
</script>
```

I want to create a regex to which I give key and it will return value, let's say I want to get value of "stock" so when I insert stock key in regex it will return all values related to key stock as PHP array, also when I insert key which has array of objects as value, should return nested array.

Here is coding attempt:

```
$re = '/{"availVar":(.*)}/';
preg_match_all($re, $string, $output_array, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$json = json_decode($output_array[0][0], true);
```

currently I am traversing this decoded json array and getting stock status, what I wanted to do is write just one function that receive key, apply regex and return value of this as result.

Is there anyway to create this type of regex ? Please advice, Thanks

Comment: Why not just parse the Json from the code and decode it to an array?

Comment: @Andreas actually I am getting complete HTML page as response and JSON is inside script tags, so first I need to filter JSON from HTML DOM then parse it in the code, every time I get different JSON, did you get it ?

Comment: Yes.. what difference does that make?

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, your solution works but can we make it more dynamic ?

Comment: Can you please post your exact expected result from calling a custom function like: `extractData('stock')` ? Do you want the `name`s? or just the `id`?  What exact structure should the output have?  Where is your coding attempt?  StackOverflow is not meant to be a free coding service.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have update my question with my coding attempt please see it now.

Comment: Yes, but what is your expected result when you want `stock` data?  Please clarify your question.  What should the array structure look like?

Comment: @mickmackusa I already mentioned I need PHP array in response, like [stock] =>[0] => [stock_quantity], [1]=>[stock_quantity] If we have multiple key value pairs with key stock.

Comment: I don't see that previously posted information.  I'll write something up.

Comment: Don't you want to associate the amount of stock with the option name?  Wouldn't you rather see something like: `['Chrome'=>1,'SuperSteel'=>0]`?

Comment: Yes exactly but it should be like this stock => ['Chrome'=>1,'SuperSteel'=>0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SBWko))

```
function extractColumnData($html,$key){
    if(!preg_match("~\.put\('\d+',\s+(.+?)\);~",$html,$out)){
        return "alert yourself of the preg_match failure";
    }
    if(($array=@json_decode($out[1],true))===null && json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE){
       return "alert yourself of the json decode failure";
    }
    return array_column(current(array_column(current($array),'options')),$key,'name');  // this assumes the static structure of your json/array data
}

$html=<<<HTML
<script>
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setSpaceId('33503761');
HZ.data.Variations.put('33503761', {"availVar": [{"id": "c", "label": "Color", "options": [{"name": "Chrome", "avail": 1, "stock": 1, "price": "$174.51", "quantity": "52", "imageId": "3eb1230d05775d3c"}, {"name": "SuperSteel", "avail": 1, "stock": 0, "price": "$341.40", "quantity": "0", "imageId": "d0a126f505775d3e"}]}], "curVar": {"c": "SuperSteel"}, "exactMatch": true});
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setSelector(HZ.productVariation.ListSelector);
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setRenderer(HZ.productVariation.ViewSpaceRenderer);
HZ.productVariation.Manager.setHistoryManager(new HZ.productVariation.BrowserHistoryManager("replace"));
$('.variationSelectors').append(HZ.productVariation.Manager.drawSelectors('33503761'));

HZ.productVariation.Manager.initUI();
</script>
HTML;

echo "avail => ";
var_export(extractColumnData($html,'avail'));
echo "\n----\n";
echo "stock => ";
var_export(extractColumnData($html,'stock'));
echo "\n----\n";
echo "price => ";
var_export(extractColumnData($html,'price'));
echo "\n----\n";
echo "quantity => ";
var_export(extractColumnData($html,'quantity'));
echo "\n----\n";
echo "imageId => ";
var_export(extractColumnData($html,'imageId'));
```

Output:

```
avail => array (
  'Chrome' => 1,
  'SuperSteel' => 1,
)
----
stock => array (
  'Chrome' => 1,
  'SuperSteel' => 0,
)
----
price => array (
  'Chrome' => '$174.51',
  'SuperSteel' => '$341.40',
)
----
quantity => array (
  'Chrome' => '52',
  'SuperSteel' => '0',
)
----
imageId => array (
  'Chrome' => '3eb1230d05775d3c',
  'SuperSteel' => 'd0a126f505775d3e',
)
```

Comment: @faraz stay with me.  What needs to be fixed with this?  How much does your html string vary?  I can only test against the one sample you've provided.  I don't want to write up a bunch of explanation before getting confirmation that this works for you.

Comment: actually html string vary every time, I got different html string for different website but they have data inside JSON, so can we just get data with only providing key and without any html string information ?

Comment: I'll need to see one or two more samples of text.  It is okay for the values to change, but I need to find commonalities in the structure.

Comment: [Json inside Html](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=cb438780533ed6a0fd5cb7b3543e7441) This could be an another JSON format inside HTML, let's say I give key "values" and it will return values array in PHP. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Do you have intimidate knowledge of what indexes and keys you will be searching for, prior to trying to extract the data?  I mean for the first posted json, do you _KNOW_ that your desired data is down in `$array['availVar'][0]['options']`?  For the newly supplied json, do you _KNOW_ you want to access `$array['options'][0]` ? Sorry, I am not getting enough traction here to confidently make a method for you.

Comment: How many different places are you scraping this data from?  Is it possible to  set up an array that dictates how to "drill down" to the pertinent data -- relative to the site you are scraping?  I presume that you would also want to have valid options to pick from.  ...like for the json posted in your question: you would identify the url or whatever you are using, then the access path to the desired data (`availVar`,`0`,`options`), then the valid options are `avail`, `stock`, `price`, `quantity`, `imageId`  I'm not sure if I'm being clear, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I am scraping data from 20 different stores and I am not sure how to do that what I am trying to do, your solution works but not a generic solution that will work for all 20 websites structure, I appreciate with your current solution, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: No worries.  I believe you will need to write a custom function for each store.  It will take some time, but I believe it will be worth it in the end.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the Json and use json decode.
I assume the 33503761 is some kind of id that should not be in the Json.

```
$pos1 =strpos($html, ".put(")+17; // find "put(" and some id? And skip it
$json = substr($html, $pos1, strpos($html, ");", $pos1)-$pos1); //parse json
$arr =json_decode($json,true);
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/jdnC0

To find the stock you can use array_walk_recursive.

```
function test_print($item, $key, $find)
{
    if($key == $find)
        echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print', "stock");
```

https://3v4l.org/5luKk

Comment: I know you added 17 to position but I don't understand why you exactly add 17 ? It seems like a static solution that requires input changes for filtering another structure of JSON.

Comment: I add 17 because it will find the position of the dot in `.put('33503761',` and there is 17 characters that I don't need after that. (Or at least they are not part of the Json). I don't understand how this is static? Maybe your question is lacking details in order for me to give you a dynamic solution. For instance, what is 33503761? Is it always a 8 digit code? Can it be more? Can it be less? That is the only variable that can possibly make it static. And you have not given any information about it, so I have to assume it's always 8digits. Right?